# Two Digit date format in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table field `AccID` where I have to concatenate `Name` with `Date` like 'MyName-010415' in SQL query.

Date format is `01-04-2015` or `01/04/2015`. But I want to display it like `010415`.

Comment: What type is the column holding the date? Dates has no specific formatting. Also, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: Avoid storing dates as varchar in database. If this is not an option at least avoid formats like `ddMMyyyy` and `MMddyyyy` because they usually cause parsing problems. For example in `01/04/2015` which part is month? I assume that `01` because of the `/` separator. While in `01-04-2015` I assume that `04` is the month (european date style).

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, SQLite?)

Comment: @BerndLinde - it seems to be sql-server based on the tag tsql in the question

Comment: @ughai, It can also mean Sybase. But lets wait for the OP to answer it :)

Comment: Dear , its SQL server. Also i have the dates in ddmmyyyy format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the date part, to get the format you want you, try this:

```
SELECT 
  RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 2) + CAST(DATEPART(DD, accid) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
  RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 2) + CAST(DATEPART(MM, accid) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
  RIGHT(DATEPART(YY, accid), 2) AS CustomFormat
FROM yourtablename
...
```

The `DATEPART(DD, accid)` will give you the day part and the same for `mm` and `yy` will give you the month and the year parts. Then I added the functions `RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 2) + CAST(... AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)` to add the leading zero, instead of `1` it will be `01`.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dae0a0/1)

---

As [@bernd-linde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3864353/bernd-linde) suggested, you can use this function to concatenate it with the name part like:

```
concat(Name, ....) AS ...
```

Also you can just `SELECT` or `UPDATE` depending on what you are looking for.

As in  [@bernd-linde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3864353/bernd-linde)'s [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eeb1c/3).

Comment: You are on the right track, but I think the OP wants to populate AccID, not extract from it. Have a look at this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eeb1c/3) that extends your answer with that requirement. (Didn't want to post as new answer since it reuses your code)

Comment: @BerndLinde - Thanks, but the OP said that he needs to concatenate in the sql query so I understand that he has two columns one is the name and the other is date column, so he can just append the name part and `-` before the customFormat column from my query. Thanks for you suggestion I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which language you are using. Let take php as an example.

```
           $AccID  = $name.'-'.date('dmy');
```

OR before you save this data format the date before you insert the data in database.. or you can write a trigger on insert.

Comment: The language is SQL, as stated in the question with " in SQL query" :)

Comment: You can write a trigger before insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DATE_FORMAT to change format of your date and CONCAT to marge name with date.

Example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, '-', DATE_FORMAT(field,'%m%d%y')) 
FROM tbl
```